# Why VirtualBox error: Failed to create a snapshot of the virtual machines Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have created two Virtualbox machine using an ubuntu ISO file.

In both of them when I try to take a snapshot it says:

> Failed to create a snapshot of the virtual machine Ubuntu.

I tried to run virtualbox as administrator but still get the error.

**What could be causing this, and how do I get more information about the error?**

Answer (score -1):

re-attach virtual drives and make sure it says attached in the settings

Comment: Can you add more detail on how to do this?